# Some of my progress... erased!

Tags: bug, badges, deleted-answers, login

I just logged into stackOverflow... my account said 12 1! It used to be 12 5; I thought that was weird, so I visited my profile. It said I only answered one question! I thought I answered 2 before (didn't delete them), but can you delete / unearn badges? My reputation is still the same though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking at your [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4718716/hopper) profile which has the same rep but different badges.  Your [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718716/hopper) profile still shows 5 badges.